# How to use crypto in Electron

Tags: node.js, cryptography, electron

I am trying to use crypto in my electron project. I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function" error in the DevTool console. This is what I did:

- Created a sample electron project as mentioned [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app)
- Added `crypto = require('crypto')` as the first line in preload.js
- Added `console.log(crypto.randomBytes(4))` as the first line in renderer.js

I get the error mentioned above. Googling didn't bring up any relevant answers.

How do I proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium already contains global, that called "crypto", so you cannot reassign it and should change name of your global variable, f.e

```
nodeCrypto = require('crypto') // or window.nodeCrypto = require('crypto')
```

and then in renderer

```
console.log(nodeCrypto.randomBytes(4))
```

Or you can add `nodeIntegration:true` in `webPreferences` block in `BrowserWindow` params, and  use require directly from renderer in some of yours modules (if you don't want to put in global in preload file).

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); // or const crypto = window.require('crypto')
```

Comment: Thanks. changing to nodeCrypto worked. I don't want to use `nodeIntegration:true` for security reasons.